# Jenkins pipeline Cron Auto Scheduler job Overwriting the user entered values with the default values in Jenkins UI after scheduler/timer runs

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating the Dataflow Jenkins auto scheduler job where user can able to enter some parameters that are required to run the dataflow job and should be able to schedule the job. User can schedule the job whenever they need by changing the cron values in the Jenkins UI/console.

The job is working as expected, it is scheduling the job at specified time and also taking the whatever the user supplied values in the input text fields in the Jenkins console and it is triggering with the values entered by user. But after scheduler/ timer runs and complete the job, the subsequent job runs, it's overwriting the user entered values with the default values in Jenkins UI after scheduler/timer runs.
"Jenkins pipeline Cron Auto Scheduler job Overwriting the user entered values with the default values in Jenkins UI after scheduler/timer runs"

Does anyone faced similar issue or have a solution for the above query? I appreciate your help in this matter.

Here is my Jenkins groovy script file code

```
//Dataflow Jenkins pipeline auto scheduler job
properties([
    parameters([
        choice(name: 'jarType', choices: ['snapshot','release'], description: 'Select the JarType to execute the files'),

        string(name: 'hour', description: 'The hour of the day in 24 hour in (0-23) format', defaultValue: '14'),
        string(name: 'dayInMonth', description: 'DOM: The day in the month in (1–31) format', defaultValue: '*'),
        string(name: 'theMonth', description: 'MONTH: The month in (1–12) format', defaultValue: '*'),
        string(name: 'dayInWeek', description: 'DOW: The day in the week in (0–7) format', defaultValue: '*'),

        string(name: 'jobName', description: 'Please enter jobName for the Dataflow job', defaultValue: 'test'),
        string(name: 'project', description: 'Please enter project for the Dataflow job', defaultValue: 'test'),
    ]),

    pipelineTriggers(createPipelineTriggers())
])

//below is the scheduling part
def createPipelineTriggers() {
    echo "H ${params.hour} ${params.dayInMonth} ${params.theMonth} ${params.dayInWeek} ${params.jobName} ${params.project}"
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop') {
        // return [cron("H ${params.hour} ${params.dayInMonth} ${params.theMonth} ${params.dayInWeek} %jobName=${params.jobName}; project=${params.project}")]
        return [cron("H ${params.hour} ${params.dayInMonth} ${params.theMonth} ${params.dayInWeek}")]

    }
    return []
}

node("test-pod") {
    container('test-container') {

        stage("Checkout Scm"){
            checkout scm
        }

        stage("Download ${params.jarType} CI jar from Nexus") {
          echo "${params.jarType}"
          //****
        }

        stage("Download xxxx and xxxx from Nexus") {
            //**
        }

        stage("Running dataflow job") {
            rootDir = pwd()
            try {
                sh "java -jar ${params.application}.jar \\\n" + "--runner=DataflowRunner --jobName=${params.jobName} --project=${params.project} 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                echo "dataflow job Failed"
            }

        }

    }
}
```